# Should I include debug statements and timeit code in production

Tags: python, debugging, software-design

I've inherited a colleague's code base, which includes some sanity checks like code devoted to timing the speed of various functions. My task is to productionize the code, so I'm not sure this sort of logic belongs. Is there a pythonic approach? For example, passing a bool into the class to toggle a "debug" mode, which would include/exclude the printing of various debug / timing statements?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating the code for debugging from the production code. Python actually has a builtin way to do stuff like this, check out [unittest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html), which has a great framework for splitting up your code to test it individually.

[Benoît Pilatte](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10972414/beno%C3%AEt-pilatte) has a good point that passing a debug argument is not good practice. Instead, check out [logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).

Comment: Not worth an answer but I would add that passing a debug arg isn't good practice and OP should use a logger with different levels instead.

Comment: Good point, Benoît, I have incorporated your suggestion into the body of the answer.